# Android change custom view y position with gridview scroll

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

My application have a "filterview" between actionbar and gridview. And i want to change "filterview" position with gridview scroll.

[image]

Like safari searchbar animation on ios.

[image]

Comment: Add (show/hide) animation to filterView add Scroll Listener to GridView. Change visibility to visible on scrolling up, gone to scrolling down.

Comment: i must change filterview position with scroll distance.  So i cant use animation.

Comment: Use scaling then.